# How to import pip installed package?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, python-import

Python newbie here. From this site : http://bpraneeth.com/projects/deeppunct

I ran the following commands :

```
pip install deepcorrect
```

Then I ran the following script (found on the above website)

**my-script.py**

```
from deepcorrect import DeepCorrect
corrector = DeepCorrect('params_path', 'checkpoint_path')
corrector.correct('how are you')
```

The python interpreter outputs the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "my-script.py", line 17, in <module>
    from deepcorrect import DeepCorrect
  File "path\to\my-script.py", line 17, in <module>
    from deepcorrect import DeepCorrect
ImportError: cannot import name 'DeepCorrect' from 'deepcorrect' (path\to\my-script.py)
```

What am I missing?

**Python 3**

Comment: Try `pip3 install deepcorrect`.

Comment: @shmulvad I did. I got this : `Requirement already satisfied: deepcorrect in c:\path\to\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.0.5)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem comes up often and is often related to having multiple Python installations. A solution that, in my opinion, is better than using `pip` or `pip3` is to use

```
python -m pip install
```

That way, you specify the Python interpreter you intend to use, and the corresponding `pip` will be used to install packages.

You can run

```
python -m pip install deepcorrect
# Test that it works.
python -c "from deepcorrect import DeepCorrect"
```

If you want to use a different Python interpreter, replace the `python` commands above.

Comment: Running the command gave me : `Requirement already satisfied: deepcorrect in c:\path\to\python\python37\lib\site-packages (1.0.5)`. The test gave me the same error message as in my post.

Comment: Hmm not sure what's happening in this case. Can you try with an absolute path to the `python` executable? `c:\path\to\python\bin\python.exe -c "from deepcorrect import DeepCorrect"`

Comment: With your last proposition, I found the root cause. The tensorflow package was missing. Everything works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well you are using python3 but are using `pip` to install the library. Try to use `pip3 install deepcorrect`. This is important on macOS and some linux distros so I'm not sure if you are using Windows.

Comment: how to uninstall deepcorrect "cleanly" with pip? Something like 'pip remove --purge deepcorrect'

Comment: @Stephan well you don't have too, just reinstall it and pip will auto delete the old one.

Answer (score 0):

Try `python3 -m pip install deepcorrect`. Assuming `python3` is the executable you're using to run your script. Otherwise, just as @jakub said, replace *that* with your executable.

Comment: How is this different from [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63040770/5666087)?

Comment: @jakub Well, I personally think mine's more straightforward. Your answer's generally better, though.